# Create a Razor pay monthly Subscription(not a payment)

Tags: android, kotlin, subscription, razorpay-andoid-sdk

I want to integrate a Razorpay monthly subscription to my app but I can't achieve that by reading docs of Razorpay android SDK integration, it is too much confusing and lacks information about how to use their services. not proper and complete demo for referring and understanding about it.

I want to know which steps I should follow for a recurring payment system using Razorpay.

## **most of the confusing things are **

- `status`  of subscription after checkout.
- `next Due` of subscription.
- How to `renew` a subscription.
- `entity` What to add and what to not.
- `start_at` and `end_at` add manually?
- Can we create 10 min subscription for testing as what we want?

**what I have done for that.**

- Initialize Object.
- Create a plan in the dashboard.
- Create a subscription(don't know about `start_at` entity).
- Checkout using `subscription_id`.

Guide me if anyone has done this before, a helping hand will be appreciated

## **What I have tried**

Create a subscription

```
// Calender API ( to set future date after 3 days)
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar[Calendar.HOUR] = 0
calendar[Calendar.MINUTE] = 0
calendar[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 3)
Log.d(TAG, "calendar:    " + calendar.time)
// ------------
// ------------

val requestJSON = JSONObject()
requestJSON.put("plan_id", keyPlan)
requestJSON.put("total_count", 1)
requestJSON.put("quantity", 1)
requestJSON.put("start_at", calendar.timeInMillis / 1000)

val notesJSON = JSONObject()
notesJSON.put(
    "name",
    activity.resources.getString(com.razorpay.R.string.app_name)
)
notesJSON.put(
    "email",
    ""
)
requestJSON.put("notes", notesJSON)
val subscription: Subscription =
    razorpayClient.subscriptions.create(requestJSON)
subscriptionResponse = Gson().fromJson(
    subscription.toString(),
    SubscriptionResponse::class.java
)

editor.putString("_id", subscriptionResponse.id)
editor.commit()
```

Checkout created subscription

```
val options = JSONObject()
options.put(
    "name",
    activity.resources.getString(com.razorpay.R.string.app_name)
)
options.put("description", "1 Month Subscription")
options.put("subscription_id", sharePref.getString("_id", ""))
val prefill = JSONObject()
prefill.put(
    "email",
    ""
)
options.put("prefill", prefill)
val readOnly = JSONObject()
// readOnly.put("contact", true);
readOnly.put("email", true)
options.put("readonly", readOnly)
options.put(
    "image",
    ""
)
options.put("theme.color", "#080637")
val retryObj = JSONObject()
retryObj.put("enabled", true)
retryObj.put("max_count", 3)
options.put("retry", retryObj)

activity.runOnUiThread {
    checkout.open(activity, options)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640272/razorpay-recurring-payment-in-android
check this i hope you will get help.

Comment: @VishalVasani I'm not using the backend, I want to do this using frontend only, is it possible? and let me know how to handle the pending or halted payments.